# How to fix period in x-axis in morris.js?

Tags: php, morris.js

I have problem on giving random dates on x-axis on morris bar graph.
I've created database on mysql that has a value of data's that represent each day. what do i need to give my x-axis the values i want ?

```
<?php if (!empty($chart_data)) { ?>
 <script>
 Morris.Bar({
  element : 'chart',
  data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
  xkey:['Date'], 
  ykeys:['TransData_'],
  labels: ['Percentage'],
  hideHover:'auto',
  stacked:true,
  ymax:[100]
 });
 </script>
```

[image: Bar Chart]

Answer (score 0):

there is no such options in Morris, you need to refresh the chart with data that matches with the time range you expect.